# Return a value from where condition parameter; if it's not exists in the table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want a query that retrieves the result of values if it doesn't exist.

Example: `select * from the table.A where column1 in (1,2,3)`
If 2, 3 values exist then I will get 2 and 3 as a result.

But I need the values which are not available in the table i.e., 1.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Im sorry could you elaborate a bit more? I don't really get your question. Are you searching something like the NOT IN operator?

Comment: I would like to get the values for the table which are missing the value that are passed in where condition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build a list of values like this:

```
VALUES (1),(2),(3)
```

And excluding one result from another one can be done using `EXCEPT`. See also the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-union.html).

Together, you can do following:

```
VALUES (1),(2),(3)
EXCEPT
SELECT column1 FROM yourtable;
```

So for example for this sample data:

| column1 |
| --- |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |

The result of above query will be:

| column1 |
| --- |
| 1 |

See this [fiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/_kvjnYSi)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is ambiguous, do you want:

1. Items which do not exist (as others provide)?
2. Values for existing items and `null` for items that do not exist?

If you are seeking the latter then you need to create an object containing the wanted values and then LEFT join the existing table. (See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/8Th-aoIq))

```
with wanted(id) as 
     ( values (1), (2), (3) ) 
select wanted.id wanted
     , tl.<col>
     -- ...
  from wanted
  left join <some_table> t1
         on t1.<some_col> = wanted.id
 order by wanted.id;
```

The CTE could be another table instead.